# How to check oldest transaction on Ethereum address?

Tags: javascript, ethereum

I have a large amount of Ethereum address that I want to get the oldest transaction on that wallet

If the oldest transaction on that address is more than 10 days then I will keep it, other address will be discard

What is the best way to do this kind of task? checking it one by one is too tedious

Thank you very much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to a node provider with archive data, you can query the transaction count at a specific block number (e.g. a block that was mined 10 days ago).

```
const txCount10DaysAgo = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(
    address,
    blockNumber10DaysAgo
);
```

> *If the oldest transaction on that address is more than 10 days then I will keep it*

```
if (txCount10DaysAgo > 0) {
    keep(address);
}
```

Docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactioncount